# Computing a presentation for the normal closure

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

This question may be too general; if so, please let me know and I can try to make it more specific! Given a subgroup of $G$, $H$, with presentation $\langle S\mid R\rangle$, how do we find the presentation of the normal closure of $H$?

Comment: A presentation of what do you want to find? The normal closure is rarely finitely generated.

Comment: There is no "the" presentation, but rather you want "a" presentation.

Comment: Although I answered this question, I'm now not sure exactly what you are asking. I assumed that the input was a finite generating set for $H$ (so just a finite set) and that the presentation you give is a presentation for $G$. But looking at it now, the question could be interpreted to say that the input is the presentation $\langle S\mid R\rangle$, which is a presentation *for $H$*, and no information is given/supposed about $G$.

Comment: (My answer still works for both interpretations, as given a finite subset of a free group we can find a presentation for the subgroup via standard algorithms, e.g. Stallings' foldings. I just wanted to say that the question is currently unclear.)

Answer (score 1):

There is no algorithm which will give you a "meaningful" output in general, even if we assume that $G$ is free. This is because non-trivial normal subgroups of free groups are finitely generated if and only if they have finite index (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168913/10513)), and because it is undecidable if a finite presentation $\langle \mathbf{x} \mid\mathbf{r}\rangle$ defines a finite group (as "being finite" is a [Markov property](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1701722/10513)). Therefore, in the free group $F(\mathbf{x})$ we cannot determine whether it not the normal closure of the set $\mathbf{r}$ has finite index or not, and hence if it is finitely generated or not.

I used the word "meaningful" above as there may exist an algorithm which will output a description of some generating set of the normal closure of $\mathbf{r}$, but then by the above it is impossible to use this description to find a basis for the subgroup. So I think the above captures the essence of the question :-)